# Callback/Promises implementation for a boolean check

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently I have the following callback system:

```
var saveTask = function(err, result) {
    if (err) return callback(err, result);

    var newid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    var task = new Task({
        _id: newid,
        taskname: req.body.name,
        teamid: req.body.team,
        content: req.body.content,
        creator: req.user.userId
    });

    task.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            log.info("New task created with id: %s", task._id);
            return callback(null, task);
        } else {
            if(err.name === 'ValidationError') {
                return callback('400', 'Validation error');
            } else {
                return callback('500', 'Server error');
            }
            log.error('Internal error(%d): %s', res.statusCode, err.message);
        }
    });
};

if (req.body.team) {
    valTeam.isMember(req.body.team, req.user._id, function (err, done) {
        if (err) {
            saveTask('403', 'Not the owner or member of this team');
        } else {
            saveTask(null, true);
        }
    });
} else {
    saveTask(null, true);
}
```

**valTeam.isMember**

```
exports.isMember = function(teamid, userid, callback) {
    Team.find({'_id':teamid, $or:[{'creator': userid }, {'userlist': { $in : [userid]}}]}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) return err;
            console.log(result);
            if (!result.length)
                return callback('404', false);
            else
                return callback(null, true);
    });
}
```

In short, if `team` is sent by `POST`, I'm checking if the user is member of that ID in `valTeam.isMember`. Am I using the correct syntax and best method to call back my `saveTask` function to save the task if the user is part of the team?

This code currently works, but I feel like there should be an easier way to do it? How could I use a promise to achieve the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a working code, you better ask this question on [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How does this code work when it refers to an undefined variable `callback` in the first line of `saveTask`?

Comment: @Gothdo thanks will do!

Comment: @torazaburo Ah, callback is on my exports function:
`exports.createNew = function(req, res, callback) { 
 //All in here
});`

Answer (score 0):

It's curious the fact that you create objects instead Schemas. However "every head is a different world", this is my way:

```
task.save(function(error, data){
 if (error) {
 trow error;
 } else {
 //Make whatever you want here with data
 });
```